# Parse JSON with special characters into Array in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing, toarray

```
{
    "api_response": "{\"LeadRefNumber\":\"23223222433534543554\",\"ApplicationNumber\":\"2323343434234234\",\"StatusCode\":\"3456\",\"ProcessingStatus\":\"111\",\"CreditLimit\":\"5454554\",\"Messages\":{\"Message\":\"test.\"}}"
}
```

NOTE: The above is the json encoded one, but couldn't access it as array even if the json is decoded with json_decode().

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to give an example of the code you've run, the expected output, and the actual output you got. And what do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: This is the JSON representation of an object; the value of its property `api_reponse` is another JSON. You have to [decode it](https://3v4l.org/sNMpl) too, in order to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$creditLimit = {"api_response":"{\"LeadRefNumber\":\"3434343345435453\",\"ApplicationNumber\":\"5345345345345534\",\"StatusCode\":\"13420\",\"ProcessingStatus\":\"145\",\"CreditLimit\":\"4500000\",\"Messages\":{\"Message\":\"Test\"}}"};

$arrCreditLimit = json_decode($creditLimit['api_response'], true);

print_r("CreditLimit".$arrCreditLimit['CreditLimit']);
```

**Output:**

CreditLimit: 4500000

**Found the solution by the above way.**